# Create new Windows Server User for existing Exchange Account

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2007, user-management, user-profile, windows-sbs-2008

There is an existing Exchange 2007 account for user john.doe@example.com 
If I want to create a Windows SBS 2008 Account for john.doe it tells me I cannot create it because user already exists. 
I don't want the user to have 2 logins. Is there a possibility to create the user-account after the Exchange Account without deleting the exchange account.

Comment: At least I exported all content from Outlook client to a file and deleted the complete account. Then I created a  new one with the same name as WindowsAccount. Configured the Outlook client to that new one and imported all Mails from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm not 100% sure how easy this is to do in SBS

Exchange 2007 does support this kind of thing, but you have to think at it a bit sideways. You WILL have to create a new user & mailbox, but you'll add rights to allow your actual user Full Control rights to that new mailbox. If they want to be able to send mail from the 2nd mailbox Outlook will need some tweaking as well, but the exact steps change from Outlook 2003, 2007, and 2010. I'm not sure this is useable if they're an IMAP user.

1. Create a new user, name it how you want the mailbox to be named.
2. In Exchange Manager, find the mailbox, right click it and select "Full Control"
3. Add the 1st mailbox to this list.
4. Right click it again, select, "Send As"
5. Add the 1st mailbox to this list.

That'll get it created. Since you don't want to have accounts like this lingering, go to your user management and Disable this new user. Exchange allows delivery of mail to Disabled accounts.

Next is configuring Outlook to access it. The method I use:

1. Right click the top of the mailbox (generally the user-name) and go to Properties
2. In the 2nd tab (can't remember the name of it off the top of my head) there should be an Advanced button in the lower-right. Click it.
3. You should get a list of accounts associated with that account, which will be one. Click Add.
4. Add the 2nd mailbox to this list.
5. OK out

Now the account is associated with their Outlook config. Doing Send As will require going in to Preferences (the exact steps vary from Outlook version to Outlook version) and turning on the "From:" field. This will allow them to select who to send mail as.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an "Exchange account": an Exchange mailbox ***always*** belongs to a specific Windows user (more exactly, an Active Directory user); so, if you have an Exchange mailbox for "John Doe", then you also *already* have an user account for him; maybe it's disabled, locked, or it needs a password reset... but you can be sure this user account already exists, or there couldn't be any Exchange mailbox associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an account associated with the mailbox, you can "disconnect" it and "reconnect" it to the account you prefer to have associated with it (this works in my environment, using Exchange Enterprise, not sure if it's exactly the same with SBS):

1. Find the "wrong" account.
2. Right click > Exchange Tasks > Delete mailbox (this is a misnomer, what it really does is delete the connection between the account and the mailbox).  If you delete the account, that also really just disconnects the mailbox.
3. Find the mail store where the mailbox is located.  Right click the "maiboxes" folder for that store and select "run cleanup agent."

   4. That should give you a red X next to the mailbox.
   5. Right click the mailbox and reconnect - select the account you'd prefer it to be attached to.

Sometimes takes a little bit for Exchange to catch up to all this, so don't panic if it doesn't work immediately after reconnecting.

Comment: your instructions appear to be referencing Exchange 2003, the OP is using Exchange 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but have found it on egghead..

You can go the same route as Mary suggested

> 1. Find the "wrong" account.
> 2. Right click > Exchange Tasks >
>      Delete mailbox (this is a misnomer,
>      what it really does is delete the
>      connection between the account and
>      the mailbox). If you delete the
>      account, that also really just
>      disconnects the mailbox.

and to readd it

> Go to disconnected mailboxes IN EMC,
>   browse for the mailbox and associate
>   it with an AD account.

once again just something I've found but haven't tested as I don't have a Ex2007 server running at the moment